# Accidentally deleted URL to Story Map in ArcGIS Online - How to recover?

Tags: arcgis-online, story-map

While editing the story map's properties in ArcGIS Online, I mistakenly modified the story map's URL and now the app cannot open. Is there a way to retrieve its correct URL? For reference, this was modified under My Content -> selected story map -> Edit -> Properties section

Comment: create a new (simple)story map. It should be in the format argis.com/storymap? webmap= ####aa##. locate the webmap_ID of the crippled map and replace it in the url of the new storymap.  Something like that.

Comment: This seems like a great approach. Any idea how to locate the webmap_ID of the crippled map?

Comment: Found it! Its in the url of the app page in my content. Thank you!